# Why does min-height push a div to the bottom?

Tags: css

`div.left` gets pushed to the bottom when `min-height` is added to the CSS. Can anyone explain why this happens?

```css
.left, .right {
  width: 170px;
  min-height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum 1</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum 2</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum 3</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="right">
  <ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

`min-height` doesn't push it down, it is happening because of `vertical-align` property (its default value is `baseline`). If you apply `vertical-align: top` to the `.left`, the problem will be solved.